# Is it possible to use device authentication instead of creating own authentication procedure?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that requires login and I wonder if it is possible to use the device authentication pin/pattern/password etc instead of creating my own authentication procedure? My thought is that pre-Marshmallow users should use their device authentication to login and user who have devices with fingerprint recognition will use that for authenticate themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html). That's absolutely possible (I've seen some apps doing it), but I think you can only use it to authenticate a user, not identify it. Meaning that they still have to register/login the first time using "classic" username/password pair or google/facebook APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will accept your answer. What I understand is that pre-Marsmallow users can not use fingerpringt authentication or device pin/pattern, for those user I have to implement a login flow.